# I cannot get component from controller in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, components

I have defined a window like this:

```
Ext.define(), { 'MyApp.view.MyCustomWindow'
    extends: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.mywindow',
    ...
    items: [{
        xtype: 'form',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            ...
            items: [{
               xtype: 'combobox',
               ...
               itemId: 'comboFilter'
            }]
        }]
    }],
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items:[{
            xtype: 'button',
            itemId: 'okBtn'
        }]
    }]
}
```

Then I would like to get the component from my controller:

```
init: function(application) {
    var me = this;
    this.control({
        "mywindow combobox#comboFilter": {
            keypress: me.onClickCombo   // removed <'>, still not working
         },
         "mywindow button#okBtn": {
            click: me.onButtonOk        // works!!!
         }
    }); 
}
```

But `onClickCombo` is never beeing called. What is wrong with `mywindow combobox#comboFilter`?

**EDIT:** Added an "OK button" that works!!! Look at my edit of the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is not the problem.

Add `enableKeyEvents: true` to your combobox if you'd like the `keypress` event to be fired.

See the [`keypress`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-event-keypress) event documentation:

> This event only fires if `enableKeyEvents` is set to true.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
 "mywindow combobox#comboFilter": {
     keypress: me.onClickCombo // without <'>
  }
```

If it isn't the solution, change:

```
"mywindow combobox[itemId=comboFilter]":{
     keypress: me.onClickCombo // without <'>
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Add this config to the component.

Sencha api - [Combobox Events](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-event-keypress)

```
Keypress input field event. This event only fires if enableKeyEvents is set to true.
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it still does not work. I added an OK button (look at my edit above) and the OK button´s function is called from the controller, but not the combobox´s function. I also tried `mywindow combobox[itemId=comboFilter]`, also without success.